# Solve $\frac{\sin y}{x} dx + (\frac{y}{x}\cos y - \frac{\sin y}{y})dy=0$ ($h(x,y)=x/y$ is an integrating factor)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Since $xy\neq 0$, we define $u:=x/y \neq 0$ so that $dx=udy+ydu$. Then the original equation is reducible to

$$\frac{\sin y}{uy} (ydu + udy) + \bigg(\frac{\cos y}{u} - \frac{\sin y}{y}\bigg)dy = 0 \iff \\ \frac{\sin y}{u}du + \frac{\cos y}{u}dy=0 \stackrel{u\neq 0}{\iff} \\ du=-\cot y \stackrel{u=x/y}{\iff} \\ x= Cy-y\ln|\sin y|$$

But here we're kinda changing which is the dependent variable, right? Is this legit? Alternatively, is there any other way of solving this exercise that's possibly simpler?

Comment: That works. Although, you could arrive at the same result strictly through algebra. A third technique is by the integrating factor $u(x,y)=h(x/y)$.

Comment: @ydnmew How it can be said that $xy\neq 0$ ?

Comment: @math Because otherwise the original differential equation would be undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another technique would be to recognize that the equation is linear. Starting from

$$\frac{\sin y}{x} dx + \left(\frac{y}{x}\cos y - \frac{\sin y}{y}\right)dy=0$$

divide by $dy$ and rearrange to form

$$\frac{\sin y}{x} \frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{y}{x}\cos y+\frac{\sin y}{y}$$

which after dividing by $\sin y$ produces

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{y}{x}\cot y + \frac{1}{y}$$

therefore

$$\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{1}{y}x=-y\cot x$$

which is linear with $x$ as the dependent variable and $y$ as the independent variable.